# Maximum value of MaxReceivedMessageSize property

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I use a WCF service to connect and retrieve data from a server, but after increasing the `MaxReceivedMessageSize` property in `app.conf`, I get this exception:

> This factory buffers messages, so the message sizes must be in the
>   range of an integer value. Parameter name:
>   value.MaxReceivedMessageSize

Is there any limitation for `MaxReceivedMessageSize` property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

limit is Int64.MaxValue for MaxReceivedMessageSize

Answer (score 2):

Did you not read the error?

`message sizes must be in the range of an integer value.`

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't read the error message correctly :) 
+1, Thanks.